# does a static return variable in a function called multiple times get stuck to its initial static value?

Tags: c, static, operating-system

I am returning pid_t from my background task function and collecting them. In order to return a variable outside of a function without it being erased when the function's memory is erased off the stack, I am making my return value static and also returning a pointer to it. Within the function it is printing the correct pid_t. However, in the calling function it is recording the first pid_t over and over again.

The function that is returning the variable:

```
pid_t* executeBackgroundCommand(char *command, char *args[]) {
    static pid_t childPid = -5;
    // some code
    parent {
        return &childPid;
    }
```

The code recording the pid_t:

```
pid_t* child_pids[200];
int child_count = 0;
// some code
child_pids[child_count] = executeBackgroundCommand(currentInput->command, currentInput->input_args);
child_count++;
```

Should I be initializing the pid_t as a pointer to begin with so I don't return with an & operator?

[output showing repeated pid_t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAVNM.png)

Comment: Why aren't you returning the *value* of the pid?

Comment: All the entries in `child_pids` are the same pointer which points to `childPid` in `executeBackgroundCommand`.  So if that variable changes, then you'll see the change when you dereference any of the pointers in `child_pids`.  Like dbush, I don't understand why you are using pointers or a `static` variable here at all.

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with a solution to a non-existing problem. That is, it is an XY-problem. As @dbush says, you should return the value rather than the pointer, so the problem of the variable being erased is not a problem anymore, so `static` won't be needed.

Comment: What 'they' said, plus you shouldn't be using a `static` variable at all. You need each invocation to have its own separate storage. If you use a static variable and run the function twice, it isn't clear which value will be stored in the static variable. It may change between the assignment from `fork()` (guessing what sets the variable) and the return because another process ends up also calling the function. It all comes back to "just use an ordinary automatic variable and return the value of that from the function". You seem to be worried about something that shouldn't be a problem at all.